# can't install iOS app on iOS 7.1.1 sdk

Tags: ios, iphone

I cannot install iOS app which is build in 5.1.1 SDKs and install in 7.1.1 SDKs

And error like this

```
"unable to download app:'<app name> could not be install at this time' "
```

Answer (score 2):

This error comes in below situations:

1. Your device UUID is not added to provisional profile.
2. Target device OS is less than the deployment target OS which you have set in your project settings.